# How to Build windows supported Python exe files from Jenkins Linux server

Tags: python, jenkins, cross-compiling, wine

We have a linux jenkins server for the build prepration. We need to create one windows supported python executable build through this jenkins. How this possible

I have tried it by using wine as below

```
wine python-3.8.7.exe

wine /usr/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

wine /usr/bin/pyinstaller --onefile --name=myapp main.py
```

But it trigger following error

`wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python-3.8.7.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using a mix of `Docker` and `Wine` first install `Docker` on your `Jenkins` server https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ then create a `Dockerfile` in your project directory with this inside:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wine32 python3-pip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN wine python -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    wine pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    wine pip install pyinstaller

ENTRYPOINT [ "wine", "pyinstaller", "--onefile", "--name=myapp", "main.py" ]
```

it contain what we need, then build it `docker build -t myapp-builder .` then run `Docker` to create the Python executable `docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app myapp-builder`

Now using this setup you should be able to build Windows-supported Python executables from your `Jenkins` Linux server.